# Client integration test with velocity and jasmine on Meteor

Tags: meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

I made this test:

```
describe('SignIn', function () {
it('should be able to login normal user', function (done) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword('example@gmail.com', '000000', function (err) {
        expect(err).toBeUndefined();
        done();
    });
  });
});
```

And I get the following error:

```
Expected { error : 403, reason : 'User not found', details : undefined, message : 'User not found [403]', errorType : 'Meteor.Error' } to be undefined. While the user exists (can log in with the form)
```

But I can signin as 'example@gmail.com' with the form of the meteor app so the user exists. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, it's because the test are running against a mirror, which is a parallel app. This approach allows tests to be destructive with data without affecting the main app.

What you should do is to create a user in a before block, then you can login with that user.

Comment: This clearly makes sense now! Thank you, you just solved my problem and explained me why. Thank you again !